# How to update rows in an "Excel-file Column" with the contents of a pandas data frame col

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT_01: I just noticed my way does not work properly as it removes the "Horse" field from the saved excel file.
EDIT_02: I have a work-round but I'm sure there must be a better way.  Work-round by deleting the "Odds" column in df1 then merge df1 with  df_odd then save df1.  This still moves the "Horse" column to the first column (owing to the index declaration, I suppose) but I can live with that.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
I have an Excel file with Horse (Odds) details that I want to update.  e.g.

```
Draw    Form    Horse       Age Weight  OR  Jockey          Trainer Allow   RTF TS  RPR Days    Aid WtLbs   CDB Odds
6       05035-  Buy Me Back 5   9-7     74  Luke Morris     Mark Loughnane  52  74  85  37      133 C       D   SP
2       /2473-  Alablaq     4   9-6     73  George Downing  David Evans     41  72  84  17      132             SP
4       1018-3  Helvetian   7   9-5     72  Sean Levey      Kevin Frost     29  78  85  4   t   131         D   
5       32676-  Vape        5   9-1     68  Hollie Doyle    Tony Carroll    26  71  87  28      127         D   SP
```

I want to update the Odds column with the "Odds" data from df_odd for corresponding Horses.
df_odd example:

```
    Horse       Course      Time    Date        Odds
0   Abnaa       Newcastle   15:10   2022-01-06  
1   Affoburg    Chepstow    15:20   2022-01-06  66/1
```

At the moment I can do it by making an "RC_Odds.xlsx" file and reading it back into python and then use df1["Odds"] = df1["Odds"].

I assume there is a neater way to do the same without the need to make an "RC_Odds.xlsx" file but I can't work out the syntax.
Any help would be welcome.
Thanks.

my work-round code is:

```
df_odd = pd.DataFrame(get_odds(date_ext))
            df_odd.to_excel('Racecards\RC_Odds.xlsx', index = False)

            # reading two csv files
            df1 = pd.read_excel('Racecards/Racecards.xlsx', index_col="Horse")
            df2 = pd.read_excel('Racecards/RC_Odds.xlsx', index_col="Horse")
            del df1["Odds"]

            df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='Horse', how ="left")
            df1 = df1.reset_index()

            df1.to_excel(f'{"Racecards/Racecards"}.xlsx', index = False)
            print("Odds Updated")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason it drops the the Horse column is because of the last line in your code:

```
df1.to_excel(f'{"Racecards/Racecards"}.xlsx', index = False)
```

You either have to not use `index_col = "Horse"` on import or not use `index = False` on export. Can't do both if you want the `"Horse"` on your updated file.

`index = False` will remove the index from export so by setting your index to Horse then declaring you don't want it as part of the output, it gets removed.

For changing the values, you could continue updating by creating files that get read in by Python then the update file (RC Odds) is used to update the original (Racecards). Another method would be to directly update in Excel but I think you don't want to do that. Another method would be to use input statements and build updates using those inputs.

For example, you can declare the number of updates first then based off that, you would loop through each number from 0 to `num_updates-1` while taking inputs for name and odds that would get added to a dictionary.

```
horse_updates = {}
num_updates = input("Number of Updates to make: ")
for x in range(num_updates-1):
    horse_name = input("Horse Name: ")
    horse_odd = input("Horse Odds: ")
    horse_updates["name"] = horse_odd
```

You should then be able to take that dictionary and loop through the updates. If a dictionary is confusing, you can opt to make a list of lists as well.

Comment: Thanks - the ideal solution would be "to directly update in Excel" .   I tried keeping  Horse as the index but then the saved xls file puts the Horse at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Yeah, that's because Python will put whatever index you have (either set or defaulted) at the beginning so you just have to avoid explicitly setting the index.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the data structure in the Excel files and use "df_odd" to update the relevant Odds in the Horse row with the Odds from "df_odd" ?

Comment: You can declare each field's data type when you perform ```pd.read_excel``` which is usually preferred. If you don't do it on the read, it can be hard to get the data types to work the way you want especially on mixed type columns (where you store a number and text or text and dates).

Comment: I've edited with a workround.  All fields are text so I suppose they are pd.read as text by default.  I'm still searching for the ideal solution which would be to use the df_odd to update those Horses in the excel file where "Odds" is not blank.

Comment: I think there might be some limitations and potentially one more way of doing this. Limitations are that you probably have to have both datasets in one place (i.e. read into Python) to make the update. Having one in Excel and the other read into Python probably won't work. Another option would be to use openpyxl to open the file and dump a formula (i.e. vlookup to the odds file) into the cell you want to update but you probably would have to know the exact row number ahead of time unless you're okay updating all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input - it seems like my Work-round is the easiest solution (by deleting the "Odds" column in `df1` then merge `df1` with `df_odd` then save df1).

So I will close this thread.
Thanks again